# Multiple instances using delegates in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates

I have created a delegate on a Script named BattleManager to handle the methods when the round is over.

Everything seems to work just fine except when there are multiple instances of the same object class adding to the delagate. Only the last method added to the deleagate works.

The Battle manager has the delegate like this:

```
public delegate IEnumerator OnRoundEnd();
public OnRoundEnd onRoundEnd;
```

I have a Effect class that adds to the onRoundEnd delegate.
I have 3 objects with the class Effect and when they add to the delegate only the last one works.
Other objects adding to the onRoundEnd work fine unless they are the same type.
I have not found anything to get arround this issue

On the Effect class I add the method like this

```
public virtual void Init()
{
    battleManager.onRoundEnd += OnRoundEnd;
}
```

Comment: Can you share how you are subscribing to the delegate? First thing come to the mind is that you might be using `=`(assignment) operator instead of using `+=`(shorthand add operator). Using `+=` should resolve the issue.

Comment: It is with the += . I edited it

Comment: In that case, it could be happening because you might not be calling `base.Init()` where ever you've overridden the `Init()` method. If you find any overridden `Init()` method without `base.Init()` call. Add it and see what happens.

Comment: _"I have 3 objects with the class Effect ... only the last one works"_ and _"work fine unless they are the same type"_,  Isn't this contradictory? Isn't class and type the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
public delegate IEnumerator OnRoundEnd();
```

is basically nothing else than using [`Func<IEnumerator>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.func-1).

You are expecting a return value - **one single** return value!

To understand a bit what happens here you have to understand what happens inside a `+=` **chained** `delegate` (aka [`MulticastDelegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.multicastdelegate)) - which internally is basically nothing more (ok it is a bit more) than a collection of the methods to call - once it is executed (the following samples are pure **pseudo code** and oversimplified - just for explaining the picture):

- First let's go back and take a `delegate void`

  ```
  // no return
  foreach(method in invokationList)
  {
      method();
  }
  ```

  So far so good - all methods get executed in order, great!
- Now a `delegate int`

  ```
  int result = 0;
  foreach(var method in invokationList)
  {
      result = method();
  }
  ```

  You can see now: The `result` will get overwritten in each iteration => you end up only with the last value!

  Still though all the methods are executed.
- Finally a `delegate IEnumerator`

  ```
  IEnumerator result = null;
  foreach(var method in invokationList)
  {
      result = method();
  }
  ```

  So same as above! `result` is overwritten only with the last value.

The additional "problem" about `IEnumeator` is now: It is "lazy" and **nothing within it is executed** until this `IEnumeator` is actually **iterated** using [`MoveNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext)!

Unity's Coroutine system does this for you internally and basically calls `MoveNext` on a by `StartCoroutine` registered/scheduled `IEnumerator` once a frame (except if using special timing YieldInstructions like e.g. `WaitForEndOfFrame` etc).

So by the time you finally retrieve your `IEnumerator` and schedule it using `StartCoroutine` (or manually call `MoveNext`) you are only aware of this very last `IEnumerator` instance and will only get the behavior of that one.

---

> I have not found anything to get around this issue

As mentioned I don't fully see how exactly you consume `onRoundEnd` but as also mentioned you basically just have a collection of methods to call / `IEnumerator`s to execute

=> it might be easier to just stick to e.g. a `Queue` - assuming each effect should only be executed once anyway:

```
private Queue<IEnumerator> onRoundEnd;
public void ScheduleForRoundEnd(IEnumerator routine)
{
    onRoundEnd.Enqueue(routine);
}
```

and then later on

```
private IEnumerator OnRoundEnd()
{
    while(onRoundEnd.Count > 0)
    {
        var routine = onRoundEnd.Dequeue();

        yield return routine;
    }
}
```

and in your `Effect.Init` instead do

```
battleManager.ScheduleForRoundEnd(OnRoundEnd);
```

or use a `List<IEnumerator>` instead

```
private List<IEnumerator> onRoundEnd;

public void ScheduleForRoundEnd(IEnumerator routine)
{
    onRoundEnd.Add(routine);
}

private IEnumerator OnRoundEnd()
{
    foreach(var routine in onRoundEnd)
    {
        yield return routine;
    }

    // skip this if you actually wanted to keep the events forever
    onRoundEnd.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I realized what was ther problem with your answer and I found a way to execute the delegates. The problem was how the delegate was been called.


            `if (onRoundEnd != null)
            {
                foreach (OnRoundEnd handler in onRoundEnd.GetInvocationList())
                {
                    yield return StartCoroutine(handler());
                }
            }`

Comment: @Saucyloco that's probably working as well yes ... but way harder to grasp / maintain than using a simple `List<IEnumerator>` imho ;)